# Deactivate and Remove Perl Local::Lib

Tags: perl, locallib

I would like to deactivate the environment variables and remove the appended /home/myusername/perl5.. directories from @INC that were a result of Local::Lib. Can anyone advise? I really would like to get back to the state of perl ENV vars and @INC folders before Local::Lib. I am on Fedora 16.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you read [the instructions](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib#-deactivate)?  In your shell,

```
eval $(perl -Mlocal::lib=--deactivate-all)
```